# How to sketch a function such as r(t) = (t^2)i + (t^3)j

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

How can I sketch this function by hand? I am not even sure what I should be expecting,.

Comment: Take values for t, evaluate both $x=t^2,y=t^3$, draw the pairs $(x,y)$ and then join them

Comment: For positive values of $t$, we have $y=t^3=t^2\cdot t=x\sqrt{x}$

Comment: This is perfect thanks for your help!

Comment: $\large y = x^{3/2}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin and Semsem : This is INCORRECT. The correct solution is $x=y^{2/3}$, which is not the same graph.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the pairs $x\mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j}$ satisfy $x=y^{2/3}$ and that $y$ ranges throughout $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

The vector is 
$$\mathbf{r}(t)=x\mathbf{\hat{i}}+y\mathbf{\hat{j}}=t^2\mathbf{\hat{i}}+t^3\mathbf{\hat{j}}\\
\implies x=t^2,y=t^3\\
\implies t=\sqrt{x},y=t^3,\text{ which holds }\forall x\geq0\\
\implies y=x\sqrt{x}$$
This gives us the graph as the graph of the function $\boxed{y=x\sqrt{x}}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2_{x\geq0,y\geq0}$, i.e., the coordinates of any point on the graph is $(x,x\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: This is incorrect. You have neglected half of the graph. Please note the difference between your solution and mine. You have assumed that both coordinates are positive, which is in fact false.

Comment: @MPW True. However, if $x=t^2$, then in the real numbers, $t$can be written as $\sqrt{x}$ iff $x\geq0$.

Comment: The implication in the 3rd displayed line of your solution is incorrect. You can't conclude that $t=\sqrt{x}$. You are leaving off all negative values of $t$ (that's the "half of the graph" I meant). $x$ is a function of $y$, but it is not a 1-1 function of $y$ because the points $((\pm t)^2,(\pm t)^3)=(t^2,\pm t^3)$ are both on the graph.